# AngularJS does not return forward API query data

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a little problem. The API data from the code below appears normally on the console, it returns an array with the data, but I can't return them to use them in the front-end. PS: that "name here!" I can use it on the front, the query cannot.

I'm using angularJS.

```
$scope.getCharacters = function() {
      $scope.teste = "name here!";
      axios.get(baseUrl + "/characters" + complemento)
        .then(function (res) {
          console.log(res.data.data.results) // returns API data normally, communication is working
          var heroes = res.data.data.results;
          return heroes;
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
          console.log(err)
        });
        
        console.log(heroes)
    }

$scope.getCharacters();
```

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. Have you checked the Network tab of your dev tools to confirm that the HTTP call succeeded and has the data you're expecting?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `$scope.getCharacters();` to some variable. You are calling the code but it's not being saved anywhere to be used.

`$scope.heroes = $scope.getCharacters();` is a possible solution.